# How do you change the colors of individual markers with matplotlib.errorbar?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, errorbar

I'm making a scatterplot with error bars, and so far my code looks like this:

```
plt.errorbar(indices,
                 sample_means,
                 xerr=0,
                 yerr=yerr,
                 marker='o',
                 markeredgecolor='blue',
                 markerfacecolor='blue',
                 Linestyle='None',
                 ecolor=ecolor
                )
```

Here `ecolor` is an array that can be something like `np.array(['red','blue','green'])`. This controls the colors of the error bars, but I want the data markers to be those same colors as well. `markeredgecolor` and `markerfacecolor` don't seem to take arrays as values. Is there any way to make the data markers these colors as well?

Comment: scatter them separately with the corresponding colors?

Answer (score 0):

plt.errorbar() can take argument 'c', which can be any of the following:

A scalar or sequence of n numbers to be mapped to colors using cmap and norm.

A 2-D array in which the rows are RGB or RGBA.

A sequence of colors of length n.

A single color format string.

The below code will make the points of your plot black while not changing the color of anything else:

```
plt.errorbar(indices,
             sample_means,
             xerr=0,
             yerr=yerr,
             marker='o',
             markeredgecolor='blue',
             markerfacecolor='blue',
             Linestyle='None',
             ecolor=ecolor,
             c='black'
            )
```